# string builder append format in vb.net

Tags: datatable, stringbuilder

having string builder recieved values from the datatable . datatable contains the column named 
as ename and contain the values like

```
abc
abc
abc

in stringbuilder stored this value in the following format abcabcabc.

code

 Do While (i < dt.Rows.Count)

        sb.Append(dt.Rows(i)("ename").ToString)
                   i = (i + 1)
   Loop

Expected output abc,abc,abc .how to do this?
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? There are many many ways to do this, please explain why you need to use `StringBuilder` and why you mention `AppendFormat`?

Comment: @oded i want to store these value in one column

Comment: So, you want a single string to be produced. Fine. But why use `StringBuilder` and `AppendFormat`? If these are not _needed_, why mention them? Also, if you are talking about a _single relational database column_, that's a broken relational design.

Comment: @oded sorry i cant understand what u say . can u pls give me the code

Comment: I am asking two simple things. Why do you need to use `StringBuilder`? Why did you mention `AppendFormat`?

Comment: @oded without sb how can we add dtatrow as single string with comma delimiter

Comment: [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21638/discussion-between-vps-and-oded)